# HTML Form field show/hide as per option selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textfield, forms

Today I face another big problem on the way to developing my site. I have a normal form with some basic CSS. Now I want to use the form in that way, some fields will be hidden by default, the respective textfield will be activated as per menu selected from dropdown list. I first thought to do it it PHP in some other way but that will not be proper for my requirment. I want somecode which will act on that same page without refreshing. So I need some **JavaScript** or **jQuery** or **Ajax** work. But I'm not good in this languages so I need your help.

After doing huge googleing I find a piece of JavaScript code which is working for me. That is http://jsfiddle.net/ZxLU9/

But The problem is it is only working for two option as it was given on the site. I tried to add `id3`. But when ever I'm increasing an id, the code is not working anymore. Also, though this code is using **tbody** the hidden form design is totally broken. I'm sharing my full code here. Within the code there are some PHP code, ignore that, I'm not concern about that right now. Just fix me this issue with my actual design.
 
Please
You can visit the full code here : http://jsfiddle.net/QvJH6/2/

**CHECK THE FIELD NAMED EXTRA . . . . That is the one where I want to put that code.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//change the function call from

//onchange="display(this,'text','image');"

//to
// onchange="display(this,'text','image',invisible);"

//and also change your display function in javascript to

```
function display(obj,id1,id2,id3) {
           txt = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
           document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById(id3).style.display = 'none';
           if ( txt.match(id1) ) {
              document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'block';
           }
           if ( txt.match(id2) ) {
              document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
           }
           if ( txt.match(id3) ) {
              document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'block';
           }
```

}

Comment: Got a huge problem in this. When I'm posting value from page 1.php to page 2.php, the submit button is only working for the last option present within the select dropdown menu. If I choose another option and try to submit the form, the form submitting option is not working in another word, the form **action** is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery change event.

```
 $('#select_box').change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == "somevalue"){
     if($(this).next('input').css("display") == "none"){
          $(this).next('label').show();
          $(this).next('input').show();
      //Code to hide any existing fields go here.
     }
   }
 });
```

That should work if you make everything consistent. If not then you will have to do one for each select box and specifiy which fields to show

Comment: A bit more complicated but it will work for dozens of selects without changing much. I used a lot of generic names so you can change them. I also used an attribute call data-select to tie fields to options http://jsfiddle.net/QMYpM/